# Computing $\int e^{-x} * \sin x\space dx$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given the following integral:

$\int e^{-x}\sin x \space dx$

I have tried to compute it in the following way:

Choosing $f = e^{-x}$ and $g' = \sin x$, we have that

$\int e^{-x}\sin x \space dx = fg - \int f'g$

thus

$\int e^{-x}\sin x \space dx = e^{-x}(-\cos x) - \int (-e^{-x})(-\cos x)\space dx = -e^{-x}\cos x - \int e^{-x}\cos x\space dx$

For the second integral, I choose $f = e^{-x}$ and $g' = \cos x$, thus

$-e^{-x}\cos x - \int e^{-x}\cos x\space dx = -e^{-x}\cos x - e^{-x}\sin x - \int -e^{-x}\sin x \space dx$

Now, the integral that I am left with is very similar to the one I started with, and this would be a good time to solve for the integral. However, I am left with one contradiction:

$\int e^{-x}\sin x \space dx = .-e^{-x}\cos x - e^{-x}\sin x + \int e^{-x}\sin x$

Thus I am unable to solve for the integral, as they cancel each other out. Did I blunder in my computing?

Comment: Do you _have_ to prove it that way?  There are easier ways.

Answer (score 2):

When you evaluate the second integral, use parentheses:

$$-e^{-x} \cos{x} - \int e^{-x} \cos{x} dx = -e^{-x} \cos{x} - \left(e^{-x} \sin{x} - \int (-e^{-x}) \sin{x} dx \right)$$

This will give $-\int e^{-x} \sin{x} dx$, instead of $+$, and fixes the problem.

Comment: Naturally. Never been an issue for the other tasks, so I suppose its easy to forget the simple things at times.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int e^{-x}\cdot\sin xdx=\int e^{-x}\cdot\Im(e^{ix})dx=\Im\left(\int e^{(-1+i)x}dx\right)=\Im\left(\frac1{-1+i}e^{(-1+i)x}\right)=$$ $$=\Im\left(\frac{e^{-x}(\cos x+i\sin x)}{-1+i}\right)=\Im\left(\frac{e^{-x}(\cos x+i\sin x)}{-1+i}\cdot\frac{1+i}{1+i}\right)=$$ $$=\Im\left(\frac{e^{-x}[(\cos x-\sin x)+i(\cos x+\sin x)]}{-2}\right)=-\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{2e^x}$$